# Changing background color for a text annotation to increase contrast and visibility

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, background-color, annotate

I'd like to change the background color for my annotate text so that it's green and covers up anything behind it (like the horizontal line in the example below).  How do I do that?

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_hline(yintercept=0) + 
  annotate("text",x=0,y=0,label="Here is a line")
```

[image]

Comment: You can use `annotate("rect",xmin=?,xmax=?, ymin=?, ymax=?, fill="yellow")` and you should use this line before the "text annotate", however `geom_label` is a lot cleaner

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Try `geom_label` instead:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) + 
  labs(x = "", y = "") +
  geom_label(aes(x = 0, y = 0, label = "Here is a line"), fill = "green")
```

[image]

Comment: NOTE that `geom_label` must be mentioned after `geom_hline` otherwise the line will be visible over the label

Comment: Note that in``annotate(geom = "label", x = 0, y =0, color = "red", fill = "green")``,  the ``color`` argument will apply to both the text and the box line around it (as far as I can tell).

Comment: For anyone using geom_label, note the performance hit as it draws for every row. https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2266. Found this out the hard way as all my plotting ground to a halt

Answer (score 24):

Building on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39604082/1009730), but avoiding the use of `geom_label()` so that the label draws only once, not once for every row of plotted data (as correctly pointed out in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39602828/ggplot2-annotate-changing-the-background-color-for-a-text-annotation#comment93868119_39604082)):

You can still use `annotate()`, which is the preferred approach for a one-off annotation, but use `label` instead of `text` as the `geom`.

Likewise you could supply `geom="segment"` to draw a line, etc...

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_hline(yintercept=0) + 
  annotate(geom="label",x=0,y=0,label="Here is a line", fill="green")
```

[image: plot]

Comment: I would like to add to this good answer that ``label.size = NA`` removes those black fill borders: ``annotate(geom="label",x=0,y=0,label="Here is a line",label.size=NA,fill="green")``. Thanks to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45376078/9455395