# Set a color to show clear the numbers

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, geom-bar

In this bar chart for the specific viridis option is it possible to set of color which can show the numbers inside the chart clear even for the darker option of the scale?

```
library(ggplot2)
Year      <- c(rep(c("2006-07", "2007-08", "2008-09", "2009-10"), each = 4))
Category  <- c(rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), times = 4))
Frequency <- c(168, 259, 226, 340, 216, 431, 319, 368, 423, 645, 234, 685, 166, 467, 274, 251)
Data      <- data.frame(Year, Category, Frequency)
ggplot(Data, aes(x = Year, y = Frequency, fill = Category, label = Frequency)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +  scale_fill_viridis_d(option  = "magma")
```

Comment: Related: [ggplot2: text color based on background contrast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47281365/ggplot2-text-color-based-on-background-contrast); [Is there a is light or is dark color function in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49437263/is-there-a-is-light-or-is-dark-color-function-in-r); [Changing background color for a text annotation to increase contrast and visibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39602828/changing-background-color-for-a-text-annotation-to-increase-contrast-and-visibil)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Making use of a trick I learned from `scales::show_col` you can choose the text color automatically according to the fill like so:

```r
library(ggplot2)
Year      <- c(rep(c("2006-07", "2007-08", "2008-09", "2009-10"), each = 4))
Category  <- c(rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), times = 4))
Frequency <- c(168, 259, 226, 340, 216, 431, 319, 368, 423, 645, 234, 685, 166, 467, 274, 251)
Data      <- data.frame(Year, Category, Frequency)

# Trick from scales::show_col
hcl <- farver::decode_colour(viridisLite::magma(length(unique(Category))), "rgb", "hcl")
label_col <- ifelse(hcl[, "l"] > 50, "black", "white")

ggplot(Data, aes(x = Year, y = Frequency, fill = Category, label = Frequency)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(color = Category), size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), show.legend = FALSE) +  
  scale_color_manual(values = label_col) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(option  = "magma")
```

[image]

**EDIT**

A second option which I learned recently would be to make use of `ggplot2::after_scale` and `prismatic::best_contrast` to  automatically pick the text color with best contrast like so:

```r
library(prismatic)

ggplot(Data, aes(x = Year, y = Frequency, fill = Category, label = Frequency)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(color = after_scale(
    prismatic::best_contrast(fill, c("white", "black"))
  )),
  size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(option = "magma")
```

Comment: Great solution, and it does not mess up the positioning like `geom_label` or `ggtext::geom_textbox` tend to do with `position_stack`...

Comment: Second solution works great! Just a tip that you want the aes information in the main ggplot call not the geom call or it doesn't pick it up

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

Replace `geom_text(...)` with `geom_label(fill = "white", ...)` which automatically provides a label "box".

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(Data, aes(x = Year, y = Frequency, fill = Category, label = Frequency)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_label(size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), fill = "white") +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(option  = "magma")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Please also comment on what you did in plain English.

Comment: Note that if you're using a static value for `fill`, it can be called outside of `aes`.