# Conditional text colour based on background colour (High contrast text) for ggplot (geom_col, and geom_text)

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text, scale-color-manual

Hello you clever R people!
I'm trying to create a stack bar plot showing soil thicknesses with a specific background colour and then add labels to the plot that change colour depending on the background colour.  I'm very new to R and this is the first time I've attempted something like this.  I've worked through several examples and I think I'm getting close but I can't seem to work out how to create a conditional text colour based on the back ground colour. I want something like this example:-
https://lara-southard.medium.com/changing-geom-text-color-for-stacked-bar-graphs-in-ggplot-f0e45bfeaa56

My code is messy because it's modified from a worked example
Here is my code:-

```
soil_profile <- cbind.data.frame(
  profile = "",               # Name of the whole profile
  from = c(0,0.41,0.76,1.00,1.45,1.58,1.88),                    # Beginning of each horizon
  to = c(0.41,0.76,1.00,1.45,1.58,1.88,2.48),                    # End of each horizon
  horizon=c('Peaty loam','Loamy peat', 'Humified peat (1)', 'Humified peat (2)', 'Fine sand',
  'Pipe bedding and exclusion zone', 'Pipe'),       # Name of the horizon
  hex = c('#33CCCC', '#008080', '#003366', '#003366', '#F2F2F2', '#A9D18E', '#A9D18E')
)

soil_profile
soil_profile <- soil_profile%>%
 mutate(
    height = to - from 
 )

soil_profile
soil_plot<-ggplot(
 data = soil_profile,
aes(
 x=profile,y=-height,                       # specify x and y axis
fill=fct_reorder(horizon,to,.desc=TRUE)), # make sure that horizons are on the right order
)+
  geom_col(
width=0.8, color= 'white'                                  # Profile width
 )

soil_plot
soil_plot<-soil_plot+
scale_fill_manual(
breaks=soil_profile$horizon,
values=soil_profile$hex)

soil_plot
soil_plot<-soil_plot+
guides(fill=FALSE)+                      # Hide legend
 geom_text(
aes(y=-(from+height/2),label=horizon))
soil_plot
soil_plot+
  scale_x_discrete(position = 'top')+    # Move profile name to the top
labs(
title = "",
y = "Depth (meters)",
x=""
 )+
 theme_minimal()
```

Here is the graph I get
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/la7om.png)
and here is the graph I want
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQ9Qc.png)

I want something like this example:-
https://lara-southard.medium.com/changing-geom-text-color-for-stacked-bar-graphs-in-ggplot-f0e45bfeaa56

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set a color to show clear the numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62800823/set-a-color-to-show-clear-the-numbers)

Answer (score 2):

Create a color palette which assigns to each `horizon` your desired text color as you did with the fill palette. Afterwards map on the `color` aes and set your color palette using `scale_color_manual`:

Note: For an approach to automatically set the text colors see [Set a color to show clear the numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62800823/set-a-color-to-show-clear-the-numbers/62801025#62801025)

```
library(ggplot2)

pal_color <- c(rep("white", 4), rep("black", 3))
names(pal_color) <- soil_profile$horizon

ggplot(
  data = soil_profile,
  aes(
    x = profile, y = -height,
    fill = fct_reorder(horizon, to, .desc = TRUE)
  ),
) +
  geom_col(
    width = 0.8, color = "white"
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    breaks = soil_profile$horizon,
    values = soil_profile$hex
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = pal_color
  ) +
  guides(fill = "none", color = "none") +
  geom_text(
    aes(
      y = -(from + height / 2), label = horizon,
      color = horizon
    )
  ) +
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top") +
  labs(
    title = NULL, y = "Depth (meters)", x = NULL
  ) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]